# Print ASCII building

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

### Challenge

Display to the screen or write to stdout this exactly:

```
    **
    **
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
**********
**********
**********
```

## Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I assume from your answer that it's fine to have trailing spaces after the lines, at least to pad to a rectangle?

Comment: My answer will be in PETSCII, which may therefore be non-competing. But I'll add it for fun anyway.

Comment: xnor, yes you may have trailing spaces after lines

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 47 bytes

```python
for n in b"":print(f"{'**'*n:^10}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFPITNPIUmJkZEJAlhZWZWsCooy80o00pSq1bW01LXyrOIMDWqVNP//BwA)

Yawn, bytestrings. I got close with a few other approaches:

**48 bytes**

```python
for n in[2]*2+[4]*7+[10]*3:print(f"{'*'*n:^10}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFPITMv2ihWy0g72iRWy1w72tAgVsvYqqAoM69EI02pWl1LXSvPKs7QoFZJ8/9/AA)

**48 bytes**

```python
for n in[1]*2+[2]*7+[5]*3:print(-n%5*' '+'**'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFPITMv2jBWy0g72ihWy1w72jRWy9iqoCgzr0RDN0/VVEtdQV1bXUtLXStP8/9/AA)

This code is 46 bytes in Python 2 where `print` doesn't need parens. Thanks to dingledooper for -1 byte with `-n%5`.

**49 bytes**

```python
print("    **\n"*2+"   ****\n"*7+('*'*10+'\n')*3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ0kBCLS0YvKUtIy0lcBsCM9cW0NdS13L0EBbPSZPXVPLWPP/fwA)

**50 bytes**

```python
n=15
while n-3:print(f"{(5>>n//7)*'**':^10}");n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8/W0JSrPCMzJ1UhT9fYqqAoM69EI02pWsPUzi5PX99cU0tdS0vdKs7QoFZJ0zpP19bw/38A)

Comment: `' '*(5-n)` can be `-n%5*' '`

Comment: Also, b-strings seem to win again `for c in b'':print(f"{'**'*c:^10}")` :P (if the unprintables would format correctly)

Comment: @dingledooper I was just checking that...  why they always gotta be so short?

Answer (score 10):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code, 47 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 58.75 bytes

*<sub>1. CP-1610 instructions are encoded with 10-bit values (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as DECLEs. Although the Intellivision is also able to work on 16-bit, programs were really stored in 10-bit ROM back then.</sub>*

A full program in 10-bit ROM format, mapped at $4800. This includes an initialization of the video chip so that the display is correct.

```
                            ROMW    10          ; use 10-bit ROM
                            ORG     $4800       ; map our program at $4800
                      
4800  0002                  EIS                 ; enable interrupts
                      
4801  0001                  SDBD                ; R4 = data pointer
4802  02BC 002B 0048        MVII    #data,  R4
4805  02BD 0200             MVII    #$200,  R5  ; R5 = BACKTAB pointer
                      
4807  02A0            loop  MVI@    R4,     R0  ; load data word into R0
4808  0080                  TSTR    R0          ; if it's zero ...
4809  0204 001A             BEQ     done        ; ... exit
                      
480B  0081                  MOVR    R0,     R1  ; copy R0 to R1
480C  03B9 0007             ANDI    #7,     R1  ; isolate the 3 least significant bits
                      
480E  0275            line  PSHR    R5          ; save R5 on the stack
480F  0082                  MOVR    R0,     R2  ; copy R0 to R2
4810  0066                  SLR     R2,     2   ; right-shift R2 by 3 positions
4811  0062                  SLR     R2
4812  03BA 0007             ANDI    #7,     R2  ; isolate the 3 least significant bits
4814  00D5                  ADDR    R2,     R5  ; add that to R5
4815  0083                  MOVR    R0,     R3  ; copy R0 to R3
4816  02BA 0057             MVII    #$0057, R2  ; load the value of a white '*' in R2
                      
4818  026A            char  MVO@    R2,     R5  ; write the character
4819  033B 0040             SUBI    #$40,   R3  ; subtract 64 from R3
481B  0223 0004             BPL     char        ; keep drawing while it's positive
                      
481D  02B5                  PULR    R5          ; restore R5
481E  02FD 0014             ADDI    #20,    R5  ; advance to the next line
                      
4820  0011                  DECR    R1          ; decrement R1
4821  022C 0014             BNEQ    line        ; draw another line if it's not zero
4823  0220 001D             B       loop        ; or process the next value
                      
4825  02BD 0030       done  MVII    #$30,   R5  ; R5 = pointer into STIC registers
4827  0268                  MVO@    R0,     R5  ; no horizontal delay
4828  0268                  MVO@    R0,     R5  ; no vertical delay
4829  0268                  MVO@    R0,     R5  ; no border extension
                      
482A  0017            spin  DECR    R7          ; loop forever
                      
482B  0062            data  DECLE   $062        ; data format: WWWWPPPNNN
482C  00DF                  DECLE   $0DF        ; W = width - 1
482D  0243                  DECLE   $243        ; P = left padding
482E  0000                  DECLE   0           ; N = number of lines
```

### Output

[image: screenshot]

*<sup>made with [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/%7Eim14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>81</s> <s>72</s> 60 bytes

```haskell
unlines[(' '<$['1'..a])++("**"<*[a..'9'])|a<-"998888888555"]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhY3bUrzcjLzUoujNdQV1G1UotUN1fX0EmM1tbU1lLS0lGy0ohP19NQt1WM1axJtdJUsLS0gwNTUVCkWYsba3MTMPNuC0pLgkiKFNIjYggUQGgA)

-9 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334)

-9 byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121)

Uses the range syntax [a..'9'] to do substraction.

Comment: Funny how using the `do` block to bind `('\n':)` only ties! In any case you can go down to 79 with `init$unlines` instead--or drop the `init`, since OP's own "canonical" answer has a trailing newline too.

Comment: [...you can also kill the `f=`, for that matter](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhY3PUrzcjLzUotVUvI1EnWSNW10qzILoi11LHRMY6ONdMx1jGOtixSSVYoUEhXUFdS1tYs0jAx0jbQSNdW11LmKbItSC3IykxNLUiHmrc1NzMyzLSgtCS4pUkiDiC1YAKEB)

Comment: Haha, I was so busy golfing intercalate (see my [tips answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266748/46901)) that I totally forgot about `unlines`. Thanks!

Comment: You can save one byte with the (more boring) `unlines[...|a<-[9,9,8,8,...]]`. Then using `<$` and `<*` instead of replicate can save a few more, which also allows switching from a list of integers to a string

Comment: @ovs Can you show me the code? When using `<$`, I have to add any parentheses to fix operator precedence with `++`.

Comment: Yeah you have to do that, `(' '<$[1..a])++("**"<*[a..9])` works. Replace `1` and `9` with `'1'` and `'9'` respectively to store the values for `a` as a string. This idea is basically shown in [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52949/64121) and its comments.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```perl
say$"x(5-$_/2),'*'x$_ for 2,2,(4)x7,(10)x3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqULDVFclXt9IU0ddS71CJV4hLb9IwUjHSEfDRLPCXEfD0ECzwvj//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Comment: Nice answer! Can't beat it, but here's a slightly more naiive approach for the same bytecount: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJAQi0tLiUKox0lMBMMMdcR0NJS0upwlRBT0Vfs8L4//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DA30DAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings Yeah, I had tried that, too, and came up with the same count, so I went with the slightly fancier one.

Answer (score 5):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>60</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
/a/**//s/   a//w/
aaaaa//b/
sa/ s
 sbbbbbbbwww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcGxDcAwDAPBXlOwdvMz0UCAFOlYaHwZRu7yOe@TGcxaECQZmvIFm4pRStm/7p45)

-1 byte thanks to [@Philippos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72726/philippos)

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcEhDsAwDARB7lccDlngF12kSgVhBn6@o6ozdVzvUzOYtSCRZGj8CdhEGmUo9y@6e@YC "/// – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 45 bytes

Quite straight forward, with some optimisations:

- starting with 3 trailing spaces, which can later be turned into `*`
- of course using the `p` flag for saving one byte
- `s/ /**/4` to simply replace one space by two `*`
- `h;H;G` to produce three identical lines

```
s/^/    **   /p;p
s/ /**/4p;h;H;G;p;p
s/ /*/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/Tl8BCLS0gIR@gXUBV7G@gr6Wlr5JgXWGtYe1uzVcTD/9/38A)

Comment: This is really nice

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 65 bytes

```sh
repeat 2 <<<'    **'
repeat 7 <<<'   ****'
repeat 3 <<<**********
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/KLUgNbFEwUjBxsZGXQEItLTUuaCC5jBBLS0kUWOQqBYc/P8PAA)

It's pretty basic, clever tricks like left-padding *`l:expr::string1:`* didn't help.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68358) by [PoolloverNathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88524/poollovernathan)

Comment: thanks, but those changes don't run

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.11 (<s>69</s> 67 bytes <s>nice</s>)

```py
print(''.join(map(lambda a,c:f"{'*'*a:^10}\n"*c,(2,4,10),(2,7,3))))
```

removed parentheses around fstring
thanks to @corvus_192

Comment: -2 bytes by removing the parentheses around the f-string.

Comment: Welcome to code golf!  Not a big deal, but it's considered good form to wait a week or more before answering your own question.

Comment: @Jonah I disagree, this helps to add a "Canonical" solution, which can remove ambiguity from the question, and I can't see how it could harm it.

Comment: @ATaco There is discussion about this on [Code Golf Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/self-answering-kick-starts-answers-or-discourages-them).

Comment: @ATaco: Also note the meta consensus against this does not prohibit a canonical reference.  Those can be included in the OP, and should be focused on clarity rather than golfiness.  What is discouraged is immediately posting a competitive golf solution.

Comment: @Jonah I'm sorry, I didn't know this, thank you for clarifying that, this problem was something we tried to golf with friends and I wanted to see what other people could do to solve it, I'm again sorry for posting answer earlier

Comment: No apology necessary!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 97 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 12.125 bytes

```
»ƛ⁼c»yøḊ×v*øm
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiwrvGm+KBvGPCu3nDuOG4isOXdirDuG0iLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
0000111111001110001100010001100001000110001001001010100111011011101111010100110110101111000100100
```

**Explanation**:

```
»ƛ⁼c»yøḊ×v*øm
»ƛ⁼c»          Decompresses integer => 122753
     yøḊ       Interleave, Run-length decoding => [1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5]
        ×v*    Map repeat asterisk n times
           øm  Palindromise, center and join by newlines
```

The more trivial answer [`»ɽβ≬ǓG»f×v*øm`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLCu8m9zrLiiazHk0fCu2bDl3Yqw7htIiwiIiwiIl0=) has a higher vyncode score (probably because the compressed part is longer).

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9TCIsIiIsIsK74oinOuKBvMK7MTbPhG3DlyoiLCIiLCIiXQ==) for 10.25 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLCu+KMkMeNwr7Cu+KChM+EbcOXKsKnIiwiIiwiIl0=) for 11/10.5 flagless, [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJMIiwiIiwiwrvijJDHjcK+wrvigoTPhG3DlyoiLCIiLCIiXQ==) for 10/9.375

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 59 bytes

*-5 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```javascript
for(n of"443333333000")print("".padEnd(n).padEnd(10-n,"*"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCNPIT9NycTEGAIMDAyUNAuKMvNKNJSU9AoSU1zzUjTyNGEsQwPdPB0lLSVNzf//AQ)

Comment: [59](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCNPIT9NycTEGAIMDAyUNAuKMvNKNJSU9AoSU1zzUjTyNGEsQwPdPB0lLSVNzf//AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
↑Ｅ333ac×*⍘ιφ‖Ｃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8To0DYTI2MIMDQ05DLmOrTN2ITLEEgZGBpwaehpauhpa3KpGKpoKagYqWhp/f8PAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
↑Ｅ333ac×*⍘ιφ
```

Output the first five columns of the figure, whose heights are the hexadecimal digits `333ac`, starting at the bottom working up.

```
‖Ｃ
```

Make a mirror copy to complete the figure.

Comment: This outputs the wrong building, it's not tall enough

Comment: @ATaco You're right, I miscounted. That's a shame, it's going to cost me at least one byte to fix...

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
#p#Þ#Þ555ì Ëç*²Ãû
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=I3Aj3iPeNTU17CDL5yqyw/s)

```
#p#Þ#Þ555ì Ëç*²Ãû
#p#Þ#Þ555             :Compressed integer 112222222555
         ì            :To digit array
           Ë          :Map
            ç         :  Repeat
             *²       :    "*" duplicated
               Ã      :End map
                û     :Centre pad with spaces to the length of the longest
                      :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
2_4··♂∙]⌂*♂Ωn
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98o3uTQ9kPbH81setQxM/ZRT5MWkHluZd7//wA)

**Explanation:**

```python
2             # Push 2
 _            # Duplicate it
  4           # Push 4
   ··         # Quadruplicate it twice
     ♂        # Push 10
      ∙       # Triplicate it
       ]      # Wrap all values on the stack into a list: [2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,10,10,10]
        ⌂*    # Convert each to strings with that many "*"
          ♂Ω  # Centralize the strings to length 10
            n # Join the list of padded strings by newlines
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## 6510-Assembler for C64, 42 bytes

```
*=$c000
  ldy #23
  lda #32
w ldx data,y
q jsr $ffd2
  dex
  bpl q
  eor #10
  dey
  bpl w
  rts

data
!byte 9,29,9,29,9,32,3,35,3,35,3,35,3,35,3,35,3,35,3,36,1,37,1,3
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! I've updated the formatting a bit, feel free to make any changes if I messed something up.

Comment: That is 42 bytes assembles, isn't it? Excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 47 bytes

```lua
explode"112222222555"|rep(" ",5-x)..rep("**",x)
```

Relatively self explanatory, explodes the string `112222222555` into a list of single characters, each of which represents half the width of the building as it goes down. Then, maps over that list, replacing each entry with a string of `5-x` spaces, and `2*x` asterisks, which effectively rebuilds it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@1oiAnPyVVydDQCAJMTU2VaopSCzSUFJR0THUrNPX0wDwtLSWdCs3//wE)

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch, 134 bytes

**NOTE: This code assumes that `x` is already displayed. To see the full *STDOUT* as it is, you should drag the list to the full screen.**

Direct solution. Had to add some spaces so it would align up nicely because when Scratch displays lists, line numbers are displayed *and* modify the position of their corresponding item.

Alternatively, [0 bytes](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/924985644/)

[image]

[image]

```
define
delete[all v]of[x v
add[       **]to[x v
add[       **]to[x v
repeat(7
add[      ****]to[x v
end
repeat(3
add[**********]to[x v
```

[A joke about line lengths](https://xkcd.com/276/)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>52</s> <s>33</s>, 31 bytes

19 bytes saved thanks to Jonah. 2 bytes more by switching from index origin 1 to 0

```
'* '[2 7 3⌿⊃(⊂10⍴2)⊤¨975 903 0]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv7qWgnq0kYK5gvGjnv2Pupo1HnU1GRo86t1ipPmoa8mhFZbmpgqWBsYKBrH/geq5/qdxcQEA)

Original code:

```
m←12 5⍴' '⋄((∊10 35 15⍴¨(⊂5⍴2)⊤¨1 3 31)/,m)←'#'⋄m,⌽m
```

Comment: This translation of my J answer seems to work as a snippet for 32: `'* '[1+2 7 3⌿↑(2⊥⍣¯1¨975 903 0)]`.  Perhaps you can convert it to a fn / improve it?

Comment: @Jonah Thanks. 33 is the best I can get in APL+WIN. Still a vast improvement.

Answer (score 3):

## C# (.NET 4.7.2), <strike>92</strike> <strike>90</strike> <strike>87</strike> 88 bytes

```csharp
foreach(var x in "443333333000")Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(x-48).PadRight(58-x,'*'));
```

Edit: @corvus_192 pointed out that using 48 instead of '0' would save a few chars. Thanks!

Implementation of Arnauld's JS version:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266751/120291

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: `'0'` is 48 in ascii, so you can use `"".PadRight(x-48).PadRight(58-x,'*')`

Comment: I had thought of that, but thought it was a wash. The reduction of 10-x+'0' to 58-x is a serious saver though lol Thanks!

Comment: Why is your string and @Arnauld's different?

Comment: Incorrect copy from testing. I've corrected the text and bytesize for the right sequence now.

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7Wzc3Py9ctzkjNyfn/Py2/KDUxOUOjLLFIoUIhM0/JxMQYAgwMDJQ0nfPzivNzUvXCizJLUn0y81I1lJT0AhJTfFLTSjQqVC00QZygzPSMEg1TC90KHXUtdU1N6///AQ "C# (Mono C# Shell) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Commodore [BASIC V2](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC) or compatible interpreter (Most notably the Commodore C64 or C128) - non-competing/just for fun - 106 tokenised BASIC bytes

```
0reada,b,c:s=1:on-(a<.)goto2:forx=1toc:ifsthen?spc(a);:s=.
1fory=1tob:?"**";:next:?:s=1:next:goto
2data4,1,2,3,2,7,0,5,3,-1,,
```

Here it is in action:

[image: Commodore C64 PETSCII building]

I will add a better explanation later, but for those who maybe are unfamiliar with Commodore BASIC, here is a more readable listing of broadly the same outcome that I made in order to work out the logic before I minimised and crunched the BASIC listing into the three lines in this entry:

[image: Commodore C64 PETSCII building, but non-minimised and non-crunched]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this marked as non-competing? It seems like a perfectly valid solution to me...

Comment: Because PETSCII !== ASCII - the challenge states ASCII, which I assume is 8-bit ASCII and the original 7-bit ASCII standard.

Comment: The character code for '*' is the same in ASCII and PETSCII.

Comment: That still doesn't mean that ASCII and PETSCII are the same

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 64 bytes (Thanks [Julian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97729/julian)!)

```powershell
4,4,(,3*7),0,0,0|%{$_}|%{""|% *ht($_-'0')|% *ht(10-($_-'0'))'*'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30THREdDx1jLXFPHAARrVKtV4muBpJJSjaqCVkaJhkq8rrqBuiaUZ2igCxPRVNdSr/3/HwA)

<s># [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 85 bytes</s>

```powershell
foreach($n in 4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0){"".PadRight($n-'0').PadRight(10-($n-'0'),'*')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/KDUxOUNDJU8hM0/BRMdExxgFGoCgZrWSkl5AYkpQZnpGCVCprrqBuiZCwNBAFyaoo66lrln7/z8A)

# [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 64 bytes

```powershell
foreach($n in $c){"".PadRight($n-'0').PadRight(10-($n-'0'),'*')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqxgq2CiY6JjjAINQPB/Wn5RamJyhoZKnkJmnoJKsma1kpJeQGJKUGZ6RglQVFfdQF0TIWBooAsT1FHXUtes/f8fAA)

Thanks to [@lost_in_a_musical_note](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266781/91342)'s answer for laying the groundwork!

Comment: Sorry, I do not think your solution is valid, you need to include the declaration of `$c` in your byte count, e.g. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/KDUxOUNDJU8hM0/BRMdExxgFGoCgZrWSkl5AYkpQZnpGCVCprrqBuiZCwNBAFyaoo66lrln7/z8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Julian You're right, wanted to test the waters but it probably is a bit unfair. I'll update soon!

Comment: :) here is a [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30THREdDx1jLXFPHAARrVKtV4muBpJJSjaqCVkaJhkq8rrqBuiaUZ2igCxPRVNdSr/3/HwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") version of your solution: I replaced the `foreach` with a pipe, `PadRight` with `|% *ht`, and combined the seven threes into `(,3*7)`

Comment: Awesome @Julian! Updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 107 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>->>--[<+>++++++]<->++++++++++>++[-<<<....>..>.>]+++++++[-<<<...>....>.>]+++[-<<..........>.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTjcaCG1i7ey0gYSunZ2ubrSNtp02GMTa6EJZIABkAlXa2OgBgR0I2cVCZWDCdhApsDhITA8OQIL//wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
'* '{~2 7 3#:@#975,903,0:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1bUU1KvrjBTMFYyVrRyULc1NdSwNjHUMrP5rcqUmZ@QrpKmrc6VWZJaAKBBfWQ9oirqCrUKstV68kUIsyDwDLgUg0NJCorS0yKC14AAHU/M/AA)

This just encodes the full rows as binary numbers, then duplicates them according to the 2 7 3 frequency.  This results in a 12 by 10 binary matrix, which is converted to ascii.

I didn't find a way to exploit the symmetry in a way that beats this.

Comment: I imagine you came across something like this in your investigation, but the best I could come up with for exploiting symmetry is 27b: [`(,.~|."1)'*'#~"+2 7 3#1 2 5`](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNQa6VgoADE/zV09Opq9JQMNdW11JXrlLSNFMwVjJUNFYwUTP9rcqUmZ@QrpP0HAA)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien, Yeah, I tried a few approaches like that but couldn't get the byte count down.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>88</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```
=let(c,"**",n,"**
",e,"    "&n,f,"   "&c&n,g,c&c&c&c&n,e&e&rept(f,7)&g&g&g)
```

Put the formula in cell `A1`. It uses simple string concatenation. The whole output is displayed in that one cell.

The text string in `n` is two asterisks followed by a newline. A literal newline can be specified this way in Google Sheets, saving nine bytes over `"&char(10)&"`.

Structured version (80 bytes):

```
=map({2;7;3},{4;3;0},{2;4;10},lambda(n,s,a,rept(rept(" ",s)&rept("*",a)&"
",n)))
```

The output is shown in `A1:A3`, with newlines in cells. The text string between `&"` and `",n"` is a newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 48 bytes

```
42¶423333333111
3
¶34
1
¶010
(.)(.+)
$1$* $2$**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8To0DYTI2MIMDQ05DLmOrTN2ITLEEgZGBpwaehpauhpa3KpGKpoKagYqWhp/f8PAA) Explanation:

```
42¶4233333111
```

Start with the encoding for the first two lines plus an encoded encoding for the remaining lines.

```
3
¶34
1
¶010
```

Decode the encoding for the remaining lines. All lines are now singly encoded.

```
(.)(.+)
$1$* $2$**
```

Decode the encoding for each line (first digit is number of spaces, other digit(s) is number of asterisks).

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 22 bytes

```
00079){3+`**}rT{.]i.};
```

### Explanation

```
00079){3+`**}rT{.]i.};
00079)                 # A Stack of the numbers 0, 0, 0, 7, 9 (Each 3 less than the height of half the columns)
      {     }r         # Replace each number with
       3+              # +3
         `**           # Multiply by "*" (Which repeats "*" x times)
              T        # Transpose
               {    }; # For each row
                .]     # Concatenate back into a string and duplicate
                  i.   # Inverse the duplicate and concatenate, palindromizing
                       # Implicit output the contents of the stack.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/AwMDcUrPaWDtBS6u2KKRaLzZTr9b6////AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2Dx7.DTÐ)'*×.c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyKXCXM8l5PAETXWtw9P1kv//BwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
2              # Push 2
               #  Stack: 2
 D             # Duplicate it
               #  Stack: 2,2
  x            # Double it (without popping)
               #  Stack: 2,2,4
   7           # Push 7
               #  Stack: 2,2,4,7
    .D         # Duplicate the 4 7 times
               #  Stack: 2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
      T        # Push 10
               #  Stack: 2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,10
       Ð       # Triplicate it
               #  Stack: 2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,10,10,10
        )      # Wrap everything on the stack into a list
               #  Stack: [2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,10,10,10]
         '*×  '# Convert each to a string of that many "*"
               #  Stack: ["**","**","****","****",...,"**********"]
            .c # Join by newlines and pad leading spaces to centralize the lines
               #  Stack: "    **\n    **\n   ****\n...\n**********"
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.2.0, 28 bytes, 22 characters

```
+@ ×10⋯▽2_7_3-@\0"0xϿ"
```

[See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__K0Agw5cxMOKLr-KWvTJfN18zLUBcMCIweM-_Igo=)

Comment: [-1](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__K0Agw5cxMOKLr-KWvTJfN18zLUBcMCIweM-_Igriio_ii6_ilr0yXzdfMy1AXDAiMHjPvyIiICoiCg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 85 bytes

```python
Count i while i-132 {
Write 32+10*0^((i%11*2-9)^2/(((i/11+5)/7)^2*20+2))-i%11/10*22
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPX0NhIoZorvCizJFXB2Ejb0EDLIE5DI1PV0FDLSNdSM85IXwPI1Tc01DbV1DcH8rWMDLSNNDV1QUr0gcqNjLhq//8HAA)

#### Explanation

Let's start with this 99-byte version:

```python
Count r while r-12 {
Count c while c-10 {
Write 32+10*0^((c*2-9)^2/(((r+5)/7)^2*20+2))
}
Write 10
}
```

We have a straightforward nested loop over 12 rows `r` and 10 columns `c`, with a newline written at the end of each row. The math to determine space or asterisk runs as follows:

We want to transform the column numbers such that inner columns map to a smaller value than outer columns; then, for each row, we can apply a cutoff so the inner columns become one character and the outer columns become a different character. *Acc!!* doesn't have an absolute value operator, so we'll use squaring. To preserve symmetry, we double the column number and subtract an odd constant: `(c*2-9)^2`

```
c  c*2-9  (c*2-9)^2
0  -9     81
1  -7     49
2  -5     25
3  -3     9
4  -1     1
5   1     1
6   3     9
9   9     81
```

The column cutoff is also dependent on the row number:

- Rows 0-1: cutoff between 1 and 9
- Rows 2-8: cutoff between 9 and 25
- Rows 9-11: cutoff above 81

First, we shift and int-divide the row numbers to quantize them into the correct chunks:

```
r     (r+5)/7
0-1   0
2-8   1
9-11  2
```

Now a linear function doesn't put the cutoffs in the right range, but a quadratic function does:

```
(r+5)/7  ((r+5)/7)^2*20+2
0        2
1        22
2        82
```

Next, we need to check whether the modified column value is greater than or less than the cutoff. We can do this using int division. But that results in different non-zero values, which isn't good for the ASCII-code math we're going to do. We can convert them to 0 and 1 by exploiting the fact that 0^0 = 1 and 0^x = 0 for any positive x in *Acc!!*.

```
col  cutoff  col/cutoff  0^(col/cutoff)
1    2       0           1
9    2       4           0
25   2       12          0
1    22      0           1
9    22      0           1
25   22      1           0
1    82      0           1
9    82      0           1
25   82      0           1
```

We then multiply that quantity by 10 and add 32, turning 0 into 32 (space) and 1 into 42 (asterisk), and write out the appropriate character.

---

To get from the 99-byte version to the 85-byte version, we first move the newline-printing into the nested loop. We add an 11th column, which according to the existing math would always be a space (ASCII 32); then we subtract 22 if the column index is >= 10, turning that space into a newline (ASCII 10).

```python
... while c-11 {
Write ... - c/10*22
```

Now we can combine the two loops into a single loop whose index `i` runs from 0 to 131. The row number `r` is simply `i/11`, and the column number `c` is `i%11`.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 28 bytes

```
" #"@+&'(12-)\'10\9992002999
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxTUlBWctBWU9cwNNLVjFE3NIixtLQ0MjAwAlIASgIFew==)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 36 bytes

```powershell
,"    **"*2
,"   ****"*7
,("*"*10)*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9X0dJAQi0tJS0jLjAbC0tEMecS0dDCUgbGmhqGf@v5eJSU0n7DwA)

```powershell
,"    **"*2    # Creates an array ("   **", "   **") print it on stdout
,"   ****"*7   # Same as above
,("*"*10)*3    # Builds and string of 10 stars, then same as above
```

Answer (score 2):

## COMMODORE 64 & MSX BASIC - Solution as a one-liner, 80 Bytes

```
0 DATA4,2,2,3,4,7,,10,3:READA,B,C:FORJ=1TOC:PRINTTAB(A):FORI=1TOB:PRINT"*";:NEXT:PRINT:NEXT:GOTO
```

In C64 must be typed in with abbreviations.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! I've edited it a bit to improve the formatting, feel free to change it back if I've messed anything up.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>75</s> 74 bytes

Display to the screen, eh?

```
a=[1...9]
b=0a-4
c=[-2...0]
(0a,a) **
(0a,a-3) ****
(b,c) ****
(-b,c) ****
```

Pasting that in directly will fail because the asterisks are actually part of the label.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f7hxeeaopk)

Comment: First of all, it's nice to see a Desmos golf by someone other than me once in a while, and I hope you stick around! Also, as for your actual code, `Label:` does not need to be included in the byte count, but the asterisks should be contained in their own line to indicate a so-called "file boundary", as mentioned in this [meta post on scoring Desmos code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations#comment74833_19317). In this case, the expression box of the label would be considered a different "file" than that of the point, so you need a file boundary.

Comment: Also even with your current code, I am not entirely sure how you got 75 bytes. I'm getting [73 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%5B1...9%5D%0Ab%3D0a-4%0Ac%3D%5B1...3%5D-3%0A%280a%2Ca%29%2a%2a%2a%2a%0A%280a%2Ca-3%29%2a%2a%2a%2a%0A%28b%2Cc%29%2a%2a%2a%2a%0A%28-b%2Cc%29%2a%2a%2a%2a). But regardless, there is the problem I mentioned above, and also the fact that `(0a,a)` is only labelled with `**`, not `****` which is what you put in the code box.

Comment: Also, `c=[-2...0]` is shorter than `c=[1...3]-3` by one byte.

Comment: Implementing all my changes gives a final byte count of 74 bytes: [Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f7hxeeaopk)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 63 bytes

```
Uncompress@"1:eJxTTMoPCm5nYGBQAAItrRgDQyMUlpYWtZhacICPBwCDVxow"
```

It's a bit cheeky, but it gets the job done.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2z7PzQvOT@3oCi1uNhBydAq1asiJMQ3P8A51zQv0t0p0NHRs6QoKN0lsNI3NKcgMrwkKiMx2dM5wKnc2SWsIr9c6X9AUWZeiUPxfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>126</s> 83 bytes (thanks to ceilingcat)

```c
main(y){for(;y<14;puts("********"+(y<=9)*6+3/++y*2))printf("    **"+(y>2)+y/10*3);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjfrchMz8zQqNasrbYzV1AqKMvNK0jSUFJQ0rSttDA2QRBRAYjCelhZIgZ0RQh4qYoksAgIgTaUlyRqGBprWmWkaQEONNSFWahtqWtdCXAF1DMxRAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
puts"    **
"*2,"   ****
"*7,("*"*10+$/)*3
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN7UKSkuKlRSAQEuLS0nLSEcJzARzzHU0lLSUtAwNtFX0NbWMITqgGmEGAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 63 bytes

```python
for i in[[4,2]]*2+[[3,4]]*7+[[0,10]]*3:print(" "*i[0]+"*"*i[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITMvOtpExyg2VstIOzraWMcEyDIHsgx0DA2ATGOrgqLMvBINJQUlrcxog1htJS0QwzBW8/9/AA)